# App is not compatible in Nexus 4 Android 5.1.1

Tags: android

My app is successfully uploaded on play store and it is running fine
yesterday my client faced the issue that he is not able to install app on **Nexus4 Android Version 5.1.1**

App is not showing when he is searching With app name.when he tried with chrome browser then he found that there was a message

**App is Not compatible with this device**

My app is running fine in Genymotion Nexus4 5.1.0 Version when I tested with APK.

i did not put any restrictions in Android Manifiest for any screen

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.tw.e2apwellness"
android:versionCode="14"
android:versionName="2.3" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
<permission
    android:name="com.tw.e2apwellness.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.tw.e2apwellness.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
    android:required="false" />

<application
    android:name="com.tw.e2apwellness.activity.E2APWellnessApp"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.SplashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.PrivacyPolicyActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.ChangePasswordActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.HomeActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.ShowGcmNotificationActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_show_gcm_notification"
        android:theme="@style/CustomDialogTheme" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.CustomCameraActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name="com.tw.e2apwellness.service.ArticleReadSyncService"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>
    <service
        android:name="com.tw.e2apwellness.service.ForumReplySyncService"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>
    <service
        android:name="com.tw.e2apwellness.service.TaskSyncService"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>
    <service
        android:name="com.tw.e2apwellness.service.TrackerSyncService"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>
    <service
        android:name="com.tw.e2apwellness.service.QuerySyncService"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>
    <service
        android:name="com.tw.e2apwellness.service.ScoreSyncService"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>
    <service
        android:name="com.tw.e2apwellness.service.JoinSyncService"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>
    <service
        android:name="com.tw.e2apwellness.service.FeedbackSyncService"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>
    <service
        android:name="com.tw.e2apwellness.service.SyncAllService"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>
    <service
        android:name="com.tw.e2apwellness.service.DiscussionReplyDeleteService"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>
    <service
        android:name="com.tw.e2apwellness.service.ArticleCommentRatingSubsService"
        android:exported="false" >
    </service>
    <service android:name="com.tw.e2apwellness.service.GcmIntentService" >
    </service>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.tw.e2apwellness.receiver.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.tw.e2apwellness" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Please help me i am stuck here

Comment: Did you tried using latest `targetSdkVersion`?

Comment: problem is that we can not upload new apk
i tried in Nexus5,Redmi,Samsung S5 on all these app is able to install

Comment: Region restrictions maybe?

Comment: client is in india only

Comment: your app is not compatible with any of my cell phones, Nexus 4, 5 and 6. **EDIT** Check your developer console, there must be region restriction. This app is not showing in search result also

Comment: @AtifFarrukh I tested in Nexus5 5.1.1 and in this app is searchable and successfully installed from play store

Comment: Your manifest looks fine. On Google Play did you explicitly unchecked (may be unintentionally) any supported device?

Comment: What kind of camera you are using? Front or back? Please ask client about it and also add hardware .camera to false if problem is persist

Comment: @AtifFarrukh he was using gmail account with USA country in INDIA

Comment: Your client's account is US, so its not compatible with his any cell phone. Ask him to use and Indian Google account

Answer (score 0):

Try setting **`android:targetSdkVersion="17"`** to something like **`android:targetSdkVersion="22"`** or **`android:targetSdkVersion="23"`**

Comment: But i can not upload new apk to play store.
ok if i change the target sdk version then how can i test it before uploading on play store

Answer (score 0):

Your target sdk version is 17 (Jelly bean 4.2), that's why Lollipop is not supported. Update your sdk version to the latest API 23 or Lollipop (21,22)

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="11"
android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
```

Comment: It is also working fine in Emulator Nexus 4 Android 5.1.0

Comment: This is not problem targetSdkVersion just inform the framework to build against nothing else.