# app is not working and unsearchable in Nexus 7 android lollipop 5.1.1

Tags: android, google-play, android-5.0-lollipop

I have recently updated my app which supports minimum sdk upto 11, and I updated my app on google playstore and all things gone fine as it was expected.

But one of my user complaint that he can not search my app in google playstore. He has got Nexus 7 with android lollipop 5.1.1.

I have checked in my developer console and console showing me that my app is compatible with nexus 7 , 4 , and 9. But my user can not see app on google play store , it shows app is not compatible with you device.

Now I am point less that what is problem. there is no restriction in my manifest of any supported version as I am using every thing which is conman in all devices like camera and other things. Also there is no region restriction or any type of device restriction in my developer console.

So can you guys Point out what could be the problem. I am referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32622572/app-is-not-compatible-in-nexus-4-android-5-1-1) link he faced the same issue but  I think he also did not get the solution.

Please help me in understanding the problem.

Comment: Can you link your application?

Comment: yeah  sure here in comment

Comment: @Zsolt 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brokenfloorstudios.suitmeup&hl=en

Comment: A possible solution: there is an issue on tablets with the rear/front facing camera: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35166. Try this: <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />.

Comment: @ZsoltMester did you find anything

Comment: let me try...........................

Comment: If you are requesting camera permission try explicitly stating you don't need autofocus: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12290295/app-not-available-for-nexus-7-on-google-play